# If $f(z)$ is analytic at $z_0$ then it is continuous at $z_0$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, continuity, analyticity

My Proof: Since $f(z)$ is analytic at $z_0$ then it is differentiable at $z_0$

1) $f(z_0)$ exists because $f(z)$ is differentiable at $z_0$

2) $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}[f(z)-f(z_0)]=\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}(z-z_0)=\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}(z-z_0)=f(z_0)\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}(z-z_0)=0$

3) $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}f(z)=f(z_0)$

therefore $f(z)$ is continous at $z_0$.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: That $f(z_0)$ exists is part of the definition of $f$. The second line isn't really necessary, but if you want to emphasize that $f(z_0)$ is a well defined number, it makes more sense to say something like "Since $f$ is given as a convergent power series in a neighborhood of $z_0$, $z_0$ is in its domain of definition, so $f(z_0)$ is a well defined number".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is, but because the limit that you wrote is a product of limits that exist and whose product makes sense. In case you want to avoid this, a somewhat cleaner alternative is the following.

Given $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that 
$$
\left|\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}-f'(z_0)\right|<\varepsilon\quad\text{when } |z-z_0|<\delta.
$$
Hence,
$$
\left|\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}\right|<|f'(z_0)|+\varepsilon
$$
and we obtain
$$
|f(z)-f(z_0)|=\left|\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}\right|\cdot|z-z_0|<(|f'(z_0)|+\varepsilon)|z-z_0|.
$$
Now just let $z\to z_0$.

Comment: Is the first point of my proof correct?  $f(z_0)$ exists because $f(z)$ is differentiable at $z_0$

Comment: Do you mean "$f(z_0)$ exists"? If so, yes, we only define the derivative in this case (at this level).